# Why Python ggplot returns name 'aes' is not defined?

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

When I use the following comand

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='DTM',y='TMP1'), data=data)
```

I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'aes' is not defined
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to import `aes`:

```
from ggplot import aes
```

Alternatively, you can just import everything in the `ggplot` namespace (though `*` imports are usually frowned upon as they make it difficult to track down where a name is coming from):

```
from ggplot import *
```