# ggplot in Python malfunctions

Tags: python, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot in Python but I am getting error messages as if the module is not imported.

```
import ggplot
from ggplot import diamonds
diamonds.head()

carat   cut color   clarity depth   table   price   x   y   z
0   0.23    Ideal   E   SI2 61.5    55.0    326 3.95    3.98    2.43
1   0.21    Premium E   SI1 59.8    61.0    326 3.89    3.84    2.31
2   0.23    Good    E   VS1 56.9    65.0    327 4.05    4.07    2.31
3   0.29    Premium I   VS2 62.4    58.0    334 4.20    4.23    2.63
4   0.31    Good    J   SI2 63.3    58.0    335 4.34    4.35    2.75

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', color='clarity')) + \
    geom_density() + \
    scale_color_brewer(type='div', palette=7) + \
    facet_wrap('cut')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-9ab398784b7e> in <module>()
----> 1 ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', color='clarity')) +     geom_density() +     scale_color_brewer(type='div', palette=7) +     facet_wrap('cut')

NameError: name 'aes' is not defined
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457513/why-python-ggplot-returns-name-aes-is-not-defined

Comment: Yes this was it. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Python ggplot returns name 'aes' is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457513/why-python-ggplot-returns-name-aes-is-not-defined)